# I was trying to remove 'python 3.10' in my ubuntu 20.04 and everything is broken now

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to remove python3 by hitting the command `sudo apt-get remove python3` and now the whole system is broken.
I tried multiple solutions found on the internet, such as reinstalling `ubuntu-descktop`.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-appindicator but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-desktop-minimal but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: yelp but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-getting-started-docs but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ibus
                  Recommends: ibus-table but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: plymouth-theme-spinner but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-docs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried to reinstall the dependencies manually but it didn't work.